# Restore MacBook after Avast! install (stuck at apple logo)

Tags: macbook-pro, restore, anti-virus

Somebody installed Avast! on this MacBook running OSX 10.8 (that's what `uname` said) and now it won't boot, it gets stuck at the apple logo and nothing more, I was able to boot into single-user mode and made a backup. I have already run Avast!'s uninstall script at:

```
/Library/Application Support/Avast/components/uninstall/com.avast.uninstall.app/Contents/MacOS/uninstall.sh
```

But it didn't solve anything.

How can I restore my MacBook? How can I make it boot normally? I am a complete noob using Apple products.

Comment: Are you able to boot into [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)? Also, did you append `sudo sh` to that path in single user mode? It's required in order to properly run it (you need to invoke the `sh` shell, logging in as root before running that script).

Comment: Yes, I executed that as root, and I don't know how to boot into safe mode

Comment: I just tried it without luck. My MacBook still freezes at the apple logo with the loading animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link:  https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=151393.15

part way down the first page of the thread, the poster Francisco Velasco had a solution that worked for me (his is reply #9 August 17, 2014). Good luck, and steer clear of Avast Antivirus - I'm going back to ClamX AV!!

1. Turn off your Mac, press Command + S, turn on, and don´t release Command + S until you see the Apple logo
2. When you are in the prompt (a black screen with white letters), type
   `/sbin/mount -uw / < ENTER >`
3. Work through these commands, in sequence:
   `cd Library < ENTER >`
   `cd Application\ Support < ENTER >`
   (as there is a space between "Application" & "Support", we use \ after Application then a space)
   `cd Avast < ENTER >`
   `cd components < ENTER >`
   `cd uninstall < ENTER >`
   `cd com.avast.uninstall.app < ENTER >`
   `cd Contents < ENTER >`
   `cd MacOS < ENTER >`
4. Now, in this last folder if you type
   `ls < ENTER >`
   You will see a file called uninstall.sh, and this is the one to run to remove
   Avast, now to use it you must use the following instruction
   `sudo sh uninstall.sh < ENTER >`
   After this now you can reboot your Mac
   `reboot < ENTER >`
5. If after this reboot you can´t login your Mac, turn off your mac, repeat step 1 and 2 and now go to the folder
   `cd private < ENTER >`
   `cd etc < ENTER >`
   `ls < ENTER >`
   and you see a file with the name launchd.conf, you need to delete this file, type the following
   `rm launchd.conf < ENTER >`
   Reboot your Mac with
   `reboot < ENTER >`

Comment: It's always best to add a transcription, or at least a précis of any linked content, as links can disappear over time, leaving the answer less useful to future readers. I've added the content for you :)

Comment: Thank you, I also tried that solution, but unfortunately the regular uninstall method didn't work. In the end, I had to reinstall the disc image again, than you!

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Mac and press :

```
Command + R
```

This would put your mac in a recovery state, this should help & make sure your data is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall Avast from Mac on Yosemite, El Capitan (haven't check it for previous OS X).

**Method #1**
Find provided uninstaller. Usually it's inside dmg file with Avast.
Launch it and it should completely uninstall Avast.

**Method #2**
Uninstall Avast as usual. Then delete following files and folders:

*Macintosh HD > Users > [current user] >~Library > Application Support > Avast*

*Macintosh HD > Users > [current user] >~Library > Caches > com.avast.AAFM*

*Macintosh HD > Users > [current user] >~Library > LaunchAgents > com.avast.home.userpront.plist*

**P.S. Be sure you perform all manipulations as Administrator**